# Unity included DLLs size

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, unity-webgl

I’m working on WebGL projects and have really big build size(after all optimisation recommendations which I founded in web). I researched build log and founded that included DLLs takes more than 85% of build size (13.4 MB). Similar situation on empty project. Can you help me with DLLs memory reduce?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say whether you have done it or not, but it's possible to turn off built-in packages that you are not using.
`Window -> Package Manager -> Built-in Packages (dropdown in top left corner)`

You may get rid of unused parts of the engine this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, of course I optimized packages before create release build.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you'd list the things you have done already.

Comment: I don't know if this was a recent change, but it seems like Unity automatically doesn't include built-in packages that aren't used. I removed a ton of packages that weren't used and the build size was exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can change **scripting backend** in **ProjectSettings -> Player -> Configuration** to **IL2CPP** and in **Optimiztion** section set **Managed Stripping Level** to **High**.
Tested it in Unity 2020.1.17f1 in Mobile template. Size reduced from 17Mb to 6Mb with empty scene only.
Also trying step by @Pindwin but no result for me.

Comment: Worth noting that Unity claims code stripping higher than "Low" can cause undefined behavior. I haven't seen any issues, but it might not be worth trying it in commercial games.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeStripping.html

Answer (score 0):

I optimized Incuded DLLs from 13.4 MB to 9.5 MB by change API Compatibility Level from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.x, but I have same build size.